# Group dictionary keys to list of list based on same values

Tags: python, dictionary, grouping

I have the following dictionary

```
{'u1': 0, 'u2': 0, 'u3': 1, 'u4': 2, 'u5': 2, 'u6': 3, 'u7': 4, 'u8': 4, 'u9': 3}
```

I want to obtain:

```
[['u1', 'u2'], ['u3'], ['u4', 'u5'], ['u6', 'u9'], ['u7', 'u8']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ini_dict = {'u1': 0, 'u2': 0, 'u3': 1, 'u4': 2, 'u5': 2, 'u6': 3, 'u7': 4, 'u8': 4, 'u9': 3}
flipped = {}
for key, value in ini_dict.items():
    if value not in flipped:
        flipped[value] = [key]
    else:
        flipped[value].append(key)
```

Output will be

```
Result [['u1', 'u2'], ['u3'], ['u4', 'u5'], ['u6', 'u9'], ['u7', 'u8']]
```

Simply Flipping the values and creating new dictionary with values and list of keys on which they are iterated would do the magic. Just look for Duplicate values  in the reversed dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

```
d = {'u1': 0, 'u2': 0, 'u3': 1, 'u4': 2, 'u5': 2, 'u6': 3, 'u7': 4, 'u8': 4, 'u9': 3}
new = dict()

for k,v in d.items():
    new.setdefault(v,[]).append(v)

list(out.values())
# [['u1', 'u2'], ['u3'], ['u4', 'u5'], ['u6', 'u9'], ['u7', 'u8']]
```

Or use [`collection.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collection import defaultdict
new = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in d.items():
    new[v].append(k)

list(new.values())
# [['u1', 'u2'], ['u3'], ['u4', 'u5'], ['u6', 'u9'], ['u7', 'u8']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'u1': 0, 'u2': 0, 'u3': 1, 'u4': 2, 'u5': 2, 'u6': 3, 'u7': 4, 'u8': 4, 'u9': 3}

print(d)

l=[[],[],[],[],[],[]]

for k,v in d.items():
    l[v].append(k)

print(l)
```

gives

```
[['u1', 'u2'], ['u3'], ['u4', 'u5'], ['u6', 'u9'], ['u7', 'u8'], []]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

```
dictionary={'u1': 0, 'u2': 0, 'u3': 1, 'u4': 2, 'u5': 2, 'u6': 3, 'u7': 4, 'u8': 4, 'u9': 3}
[[k,v] for k,v in dictionary.items()]
```

Result:

```
[['u1', 0], ['u2', 0], ['u3', 1], ['u4', 2], ['u5', 2], ['u6', 3], ['u7', 4], ['u8', 4], ['u9', 3]]
```

Comment: OP's expected output was `[['u1', 'u2'], ['u3'], ['u4', 'u5'], ['u6', 'u9'], ['u7', 'u8']]`